# How to detect if injected (trusted) events is from chrome extension debugger interface

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events, google-chrome-extension, event-handling

Goal: To detect if the event generated is `Trusted` and generated by user, not through scripts or chrome extension.

The usual knowledge is to check for

`event.isTrusted === true`

But above check fails if the event is generated from chrome extension debug mode.(More: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-2/Input/). For instance:

```
chrome.debugger.attach(target, "1.2", function() {
    chrome.debugger.sendCommand(target, "Input.dispatchMouseEvent", arguments)
})
```

`event.isTrusted` equals `true` here, therefore above check fails.

Is there anyway we can figure out if the event is user generated and not from chrome extension (debug mode)?

P.S: I understand there are other ways we can detect if an extension is installed but my goal here is to detect if the event is user generated or programmatically generated.

(The even object seems similar in both cases, like typed by user vs generated from chrome extension).

Comment: The purpose of `Input.dispatchMouseEvent` is to send a trusted event, so you can't detect the difference directly, but you can try measuring the timings between various parts of the event cycle (mouseover-mousedown-mouseup-click) and try to filter out abnormal patterns.